# Numeric Text Box - hiding spin buttons

Tags: spinner, kendo-ui

How do you hide the spin buttons on a Kendo Numeric Text box?  I tried setting "spinners: false" in the config options (as per the documentation), but it does not hide the spin buttons. All it seems to do is remove the chrome from behind the buttons.

Comment: Nevermind, had to update to latest version.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numeric = $("#initial").kendoNumericTextBox({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step:1,
    value:25
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");

numeric.wrapper
       .find(".k-numeric-wrap")
       .addClass("expand-padding")
       .find(".k-select").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using mvc with razor, you can set .Spinners(false) like this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
    .Name("CaAchatAppro")
    .Spinners(false) ...
```

Otherwise, I've found a fiddle that has the same code as the other comment : http://jsfiddle.net/uZUjK/543/ , but I had trouble with this solution when I was disabling my numericTextBox.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Most solutions are in JS, but the MVC approach is what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
.Name("yourTextBoxName")
.Spinners(false)
.Value(@Model.PageNumber)
.Min(1)
.Max(@Model.PageCount)
.Format("n0")
.Events(e => e
.Change("gotoPageTextChange")
)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:70px", title = "numeric" })
)

Comment: This needs formatting and probably some prose.